# how to generate request pages for multiple reports

Tags: birt, maximo

how to generate request pages for multiple pages as I am going to migrating multiple reports from test to prod in Maximo.

is it possible to add generate request page button in the list view of report administration application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already can generate request page from the Report Administration screen.

Whatever is on your list view is what gets generated when you click on the Generate Request Pages button.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]