# BIRT Maximo possible to add parameter dialog prompt text to individual parameters? Works in ide not in Maximo

Tags: birt, maximo

In Maximo, using the BIRT ide to develop/modify reports, there is a section to allow the developer to add and modify parameters for the report. These parameters are usually entered by the user at runtime in a dialog. In the ide there are fields for 'prompt text' which appears next to the parameter, but this prompt text does not show up in Maximo. Is there a way to get this to show up in Maximo at runtime, instead of just in the ide at development time? Maximo 7.6.1.0 is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, I suspect you haven't generated a request page for your report. Select your desired report from the Report Administration app and use the button name "Generate Request page"  to the bottom right of the table in the List tab of said app.

This should fix your problem.

Example screenshot in a related question:
[how to generate request pages for multiple reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336253/how-to-generate-request-pages-for-multiple-reports/58346282#58346282)